# Creating Each line of text as variable and them constantly changing in a loop in batch

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, variables, cmd

So what I'm trying to do is create a find for multiple people where it in the text file it will say names and numbers like

Example of text file:

```
Beth
1234567891
Jay
2134456544
```

This is the best way I can explain what I'm trying to do:

```
@echo off
set "file=Test1.txt"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
<"!file!" (
    for /f %%i in ('type "!file!" ^| find /c /v ""') do set /a n=%%i && for /l %%j in (1 1 %%i) do (
        set /p "line_%%j="
    )
)

set /a Name=1
set /a Number=2

Echo Line_%Name%> %Name%.txt (Im trying to get this to say line_2 to say 1st line in the text file)
Echo Line_%Number%> %Name%.txt (Im trying to get this to say line_2 to say 2nd line in the text file)

:Start
set /a Name=%Name%+2 (These are meant to take off after 1 so lines 3,5,7,9 so on)
set /a Number=%Number%+2 (These are meant to take off after 2 so lines 4,6,8,10 so on)
Echo Line_%Name%
Echo Line_%Number%
GOTO :Start
```

so the outcome would be
In Beth.txt:

```
 Beth
 1234567891
```

So every name will be a file name and the first line in a file. I will change it later so I can do a addition in each text file.

```
 Name: Beth
 Number: 1234567891
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? do you want individual text files to be created for each name, or do you want the output to be written into a common file?

Comment: Fuzzman, I've rolled back your edit. Please do not completely change your question after having received several answers. People have given their tine to assist you with a posted problem, it is rude to change that to the degree you have, especially as my answer wasn't until sixteen hours after you'd initially posted. What I'd expect you to do is to see if one or more of the answers posted achieve the result you expected in the question you originally posed, and mark the most suitable one as accepted. Then, if you have a new question then post a new question, perhaps this time a truthful one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65417881.txt"

rem make sure arrays are empty
For %%b IN (name number) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b[ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

rem Initialise counter and entry array
SET /a count=0
SET "number[0]=dummy"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF DEFINED number[!count!] (SET /a count+=1&SET "name[!count!]=%%a") ELSE (SET "number[!count!]=%%a")
)

rem clear out dummy entry
SET "number[0]=dummy"

FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%count%) DO (

 rem replace spaces with dashes
 SET "name[%%c]=!name[%%c]: =-!"

 rem report to console     rem report to console
 ECHO Name: !name[%%c]! Number: !number[%%c]!
 rem generate name.txt file
 (
  ECHO !name[%%c]!
  ECHO !number[%%c]!
 )>"%destdir%\!name[%%c]!.txt"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the values assigned to `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I deliberately include spaces in names to ensure that the spaces are processed correctly.

I used a file named `q65417881.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The line data read from the file is assigned to `%%a` is assigned to  and `number[!count!]` alternately. The data is retained in these arrays for use by further processing.

[Edited to include conversion of spaces within names to dashes]

Comment: What am I supposed to change in this to make it so it will work? I am using a file name Text1.txt as its source. So the only thing I tried to replace is                                                          SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65417881.txt"
with                                                                                                                               SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\Test1.txt"

Comment: You would need to change the values assigned to sourcedir and destdir to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system. I don't know what directorynames you are using on your system, so you'd need to change the values assigned to these variables to the values that suit your system.

Comment: This is what I wanted! imma see if I can get it to display for text in the file like in above

Comment: So where can I put in set string=% !name[%%c]: =-% to make it like in the text file it will display - signs instead of spaces?

Comment: Not really following what you want to do here. If you want to include extra data in the `beth,txt` file then change the `ECHO !name[%%c]!` to `ECHO Name: !name[%%c]!` (then follow the bouncing ball for `Number`). I had intended that the ` ECHO Name: !name[%%c]! Number: !number[%%c]!` would show this (that line is not required, just shows progress and processing). With few exceptions (characters that have special meaning to batch)  the text between `echo ` and the `!varname!` (and any text after `!varname!`) will be regurgitated literally.

Comment: I included the extra data, I was just wondering how to make the name in the file have hyphens instead of spaces. So if the name is Jen Adams in the first line it will say Jen-Adams(Its to make it work for a website) so example. I can put www.googlge.com/%Name% and it will put www.gooogle.com/Jen-Adams

Comment: So pretty much what I was saying is I was trying to use !name[%%c] as a variable. set string=% !name[%%c] would create a new variable for the name but take the spaces out and replace them with hyphens for the new variable only

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to precede every second line with `Number:` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and every other line with `Name:` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. For this you do not need to store each line in a variable first, you can use a single `for /F` loop lo read the file line by line and process every line individually. There are two possibilities:

1. Temporarily precede every line with a line number plus `:` using [`findstr /N`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Loop through lines and precede each with line number plus `:`:
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%K in ('findstr /N "^" "Test1.txt"') do (
        rem // Calculate remainder of division by two:
        set /A "MOD=%%K%%2" 2> nul
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid issues with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Conditionally return line string with adequate prefix:
        if !MOD! neq 0 (
            endlocal & echo Name: %%L
        ) else (
            endlocal & echo Number: %%L
        )
    )
   ```

   This will fail when a line begins with the a `:`.
2. Check whether numeric representation of current line string is greater than `0`:

   ```cmd
    @echo off
    rem // Loop through (non-empty) lines:
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("Test1.txt") do (
        rem // Determine numeric representation of current line string:
        set /A "NUM=%%L" 2> nul
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid issues with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Conditionally return line string with adequate prefix:
        if !NUM! equ 0 (
            endlocal & echo Name: %%L
        ) else (
            endlocal & echo Number: %%L
        )
    )
   ```

   This fails when a name begins with numerals and/or when a numeric line is `0`.

Comment: The first one is more of what im aiming for. for now im using it for name and numbers but would be useful to be able to use it for other things as well. I need it to export into a file with their name though and possibly add something to the files automatically because it will need to be in every file. I was hoping to figure that out myself.

Comment: So Save like theirname.txt with contents:                                                                               Line1: Name  (Which is from the file source)                          Line2 (set for every file it saves)                                             Line3 Number(Which is from the file source)
Line4 (Set for every file it saves but with their name without spaces)                                                                                   Line5 (Set for every file it saves)                                            Line6 (Set for every file it saves)

Comment: Sorry, @FuzzMan265, I can't follow; would you mind to [edit] your question and include samples of expected input and output?

Answer (score 0):

And just for the sake of posting something different:

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion & (Set LF=^
% 0x0A %
) & For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do @Set "CR=%%G"
@For /F "Tokens=1,2* Delims=:" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/V/C ^
 "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /NR "^[a-Z]*!CR!!LF![0123456789]" "Test1?.txt" 2>NUL"
 ') Do @(SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (Set /P "=Name: %%I!CR!!LF!Number: " 0<NUL & Set "_="
        For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%J In ('%__AppDir__%more.com +%%H "%%G"') Do @(
            If Not Defined _ Set "_=_" & Echo %%J)) 1>"%%I.txt" & EndLocal)
```

This file should be run with the `Test1.txt` file in the current working directory. It is important that along side `Test1.txt`, there are no other `.txt` files with the same basename followed by one other character, *(for example `Test1a.txt` or `Test12.txt`)*. Should you wish to change your filename, just remember that you must suffix its basename in the above code with a `?` character, *(e.g. `MyTextFile.log` ⇒ `MyTextFile?.log`)*.

I had the rare opportunity to verify that this script worked against the following example `Test1.txt` file:

> ```batch-file
> Beth
> 1234567891
> Jay
> 2134456544
>
> Bob
> 2137856514
>
>
> Jimmy
> 4574459540
>
>
>
> Mary
> 3734756547
>
>
> Gemma
> 6938456114
> Albert
> 0134056504
> ```